# MYSQL show results that contains hyphen in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have some products with column `name` that look like `product-example`. I'm trying to find the same result with `case-insensitive` if i searched `product example` or `product-example`. I have my query but it's not working i have a `Syntax error`  :

```php
$products = Product::whereRaw(
    "UPPER('REPLACE(name, '-', ' ')') LIKE '%'".str_replace('-', ' ', $search)."'%'"
    )
    ->get();
```

Comment: As to your syntax error, you have an extra single quote before the second percent. You are also quoting the contents of your call to `UPPER`. `whereRaw()` takes a second argument for parameters, you should never insert variables directly into a query.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL is case-insensitive by default.

As mentioned in the [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/pattern-matching.html):

> SQL pattern matching enables you to use _ to match any single character

so you could replace both `" "` and `"-"` with a `"_"` which would allow you to match either hyphens or spaces:

```
$products = Product::where('name', 'like', '%' . str_replace([' ', '-'], '_', $search). '%')->get();
```

Here is a little [cheatsheet](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_wildcards.asp) to help with MySQL wildcards.

Comment: But this query won't find products with names like `product-name` if i searched `product name`.

Comment: @AbdoRabah you could replace the hyphen with an underscore instead of a space. The underscore is a single character wildcard for `LIKE` queries.

Comment: @miken32 can you give me an example please ?

Comment: @miken32 I'd completely forgotten about that! Would you be happy for me to update my answer with that or would you prefer to add your own?

Comment: Update away. Though if the database is *always* stored with a hyphen, seems like you could just do `Product::where('name', 'like', '%' . str_replace(' ', '-', $search) . '%')->get();`